# DialogFow unwanted response: the keyword "Negative" always triggers "Okay, cancelled."

Tags: dialogflow-es

> Chatbot: Are you emotionally feeling positive, negative, neutral?
> \User: negative.
> (**Unwanted response**) Chatbot: okay, cancelled. 
> (**Wanted response**) Chatbot: you are feeling negative. Can you tell me more?

I use slot filling to extract the users' response from: {negative, positive, neutral}. The "positive" "neutral" are captured well. If user says "negative", it always trigger the "okay, cancelled" response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-actions-parameters#cancel) when the end-user says any exit phrases like **"cancel", "stop it","negative"** etc. then the Dialogflow agent will reply with an **"Okay Cancelled"** message and clears the slot filling contexts. Sometimes instead of an **"Okay Cancelled"** message, other similar messages can also appear like **"All right, cancelled" , "No problem, cancelling"** etc.

To avoid this, instead of saying “negative” you can use similar words of negative  like **"Low" , "not good"** , and you will get your desired response.

You can refer to the below chatbot responses screenshot :

**1. problem you are facing :**

[image]

**2. Other similar responses :**

[image]

**3. Use phrases similar to the word “negative “ :**

[image]

**Dialogflow Agent response :  “you are feeling low. Can you tell me more”**

There are several words like **"stop,abort,negative,exit"** etc. which  are used as exit phrases in Dialogflow. The list of cancelling phrases is similar to the "cancel" intent of the prebuilt smalltalk agent. To find this, go to `Prebuilt Agents -> Small Talk -> Import. Then navigate to that agent and find the intent "smalltalk.cancellation.cancel"` to view the list of phrases.

If you want to add the word **negative** to your response, it can be possible through Fulfillment [Webhook](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-webhook) responses .

You can refer to the below steps :

1. create an intent **emotional**
2. create a custom entity **emotions**, add words **positive,negative,neutral**
3. add training phrases to the intent like

```
 "feeling positive"
 "feeling negative"
 "feeling neutral"
```

those words will be mapped with the custom entity **@emotions**

4. Enable fulfillment for intent "emotional" :

```
 1. enable Webhook call for this intent
 2. Enable Webhook call for slot filling
```

5. Write your Fulfillment Webhook code  :

I have written the code using node.js 10

**index.js**

```
 
'use strict';
 
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
 
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
 
exports.slot = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
 

  function emo(agent){
    
    const emotions=agent.parameters[`emotions`];
    agent.add(`you are feeling ` +   emotions + `,Can you tell me more?`);
  }
  
  

  let intentMap = new Map();
  
  intentMap.set('emotional', emo);
  
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name" : "slot",
 "description": "This is the webhook",
 "version": "0.0.1",
 "private": true,
 "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
 "author": "Google Inc.",
 "engines": {
   "node": "10"
 },
  "dependencies": {
   "actions-on-google": "^2.2.0",
   "firebase-admin": "^5.13.1",
   "firebase-functions": "^2.0.2",
   "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
   "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.1"
 }
}
```

**output :**

```
user : "hi"

response(Default welcome Intent) :  "Are you emotionally feeling positive, negative, neutral?"

user : "i am feeling negative"

response : "you are feeling negative,Can you tell me more?"
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Sandeep, thank you so much for your answer. That was very helpful. I have two follow up questions.
1) the linked documentation doesn't explicitly mention the keyword "negative", but i assume it is one of the exiting keyword.
2) do you know how to change the default setting to not let "negative" work as the default cancelling keyword?

Comment: Hi Sandeep, you are such a genius! thanks  a lot for your very delicate reply. I will try your advice.

Also, at the mean time, i have another question posted here? would you be able to have a look at?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69124168/dialogflow-simple-ways-of-passing-parameters-between-intents-and-from-previous

Comment: Glad to help @Tao , For your other question i have posted the answer.